# Node script not updating Mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am adding a bunch of records `(1.6 million)` to mongo. I've done this before with slightly less (400K) and it updated about the records, I decided to turn up the volume a bit to get more done. I imagine the process for loading via the below code is.

```
<- run script
<- grab doc
<- process doc 
<- store values in memory
<- save to db
```

Is that right? or is there something else going on behind the scenes with processing, and is this dependent on the size of the information being added. Also since it's been 30 minutes and no data has been added is the process hanging or is there more going on on the back end?

**There are no error messages anywhere and the script ran completely without any errors but no data added.**

Initialize node to run script

> node --max-old-space-size=15000

```
var mongoose    =   require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/campaignDb');
var gmaModel   =   require("./models/gmaInstalls");
// testData   =   require("./jsonBig/json1");

exports.addJsonToDb = function(){
    for(var j = 3; j < 7; j++){
        json = require("./jsonBig/json" + j)
        console.log("file #" + j)
            for (k in json) {
                for(var i = 0; i < json[k].length; i++){
                    var install = new gmaModel();
                    install.date = json[k][i]['EventFireDateOut'];
                    install.device = json[k][i]['device'];
                    install.site = json[k][i]['site'];
                    install.offer = json[k][i]['Offer'];
                    install.product = json[k][i]['Product'];
                    install.creative = json[k][i]['Creative.'];
                    install.installs = json[k][i]['Installs'];
                    install.dayofweek = json[k][i]['dayOfWeek'];
                    install.hour = json[k][i]['hour'];
                    install.month = json[k][i]['month'];
                    install.day= json[k][i]['day'];
                    install.save(function(err){
                    // save() will run insert() command of MongoDB.
                    // it will add new data in collection.
                    if(err) {
                       console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        response = {"error" : false,"message" : "Data added"};
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Mongo could be throwing an error -- do you have error handling on the insert response? I ran into this issue with pulling data because I had 2+ million records and no indexing, so it chewed up all the available RAM.

Comment: If the purpose here is to really pull in 1.6 million points of data, then there is a lot that can be improved here, and mostly around stream processing and batched inserts. Can you give some indication of what the JSON files being imported actually look like? It's not completely clear from the loop structure whether it's just one big array or several keyed elements.